# Different grid sizes(height) on platforms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a grid where in Android RowDefinition(heigh)t is 100,  on iOs will be 120. How can I do this per plataform identification inside Xaml.

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:Key="GridSize"   x:TypeArguments="GridLength"  iOS="120"  Android="100"  />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>


    <Grid RowSpacing="0" x:Name="grid" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource GridSize}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                <RowDefinition Height="280" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       </Grid>
```

This way it is not working.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried doing it directly and not through a resource?

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" x:Name="grid" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition.Height>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength">
                       <On Platform="Android">100</On>
                       <On Platform="iOS"120/On>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </RowDefinition.Height>
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="280" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   </Grid>
```

Or, you can use the newer [markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming#onplatform): `<RowDefinition Height="{OnPlatform 100, iOS=120, Android=100}" />`

Comment: The markup extension also supports a Default value, which can be useful when only one platform needs a custom value.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is due to a different Xamarin forms version?
I've tested with v 3.1 and 3.3 and with following ContentPage I get following simulator screens... so it seems it just should work.

Any details about your setup?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestGrid" x:Class="TestGrid.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:Key="GridSize" x:TypeArguments="GridLength" iOS="220" Android="50" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

        <Grid RowSpacing="0" x:Name="grid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource GridSize}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                <RowDefinition Height="280" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <BoxView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Lime" Color="Lime" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Color="Yellow" />

       </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: simulator]